# Email notification for new bounty questions

Tags: feature-request, bounty, notifications

It's a great service to get email notifications in case new questions pop up according to specific tags.

Is there also a possibility to get an email notification for new bounty questions?

*Note:* I also put this question in [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240687/email-notification-for-new-bounty-questions)

Comment: I personally like the idea, as such emails are not likely to clutter your inbox too much (either way, you would sign up for this service, so it's not forced on you). I cannot think of strong arguments against the idea, either.

Comment: @daOnlyBG: Thanks for your support! Best regards,